# retrieve values from a csv string based on priority using c#

Tags: c#, string, comparison

Need to retrieve a set of values from the below sample string based on a priority

```
string sample="|NR|ABC,777,666,hhh|NR|DEF,444,,|NR|GHI,888,222,"
```

`|NR|` denotes new row

```
string[] priority={"DEF","GHI","ABC","JKL","MNO"}
```

I need to check the first value in Priority with the sample string and retrieve non-empty values and if any value is empty, need to check the second priority and retrieve the corresponding value from sample string

Expected result array values : `444,222,hhh`

`DEF` values are checked initially, `444` is retrieved and rest are empty, then  `GHI` with next priority is checked, `222` is retrieved. As the third value is empty, ABC with next priority is checked and 'hhh' is retrived

Kindly help me with this solution in C# Code

Comment: What have you tried? We´re not doing your work, you have to provide some own affords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first split your string with `|NR|` and `,`
- then sort the array by the first item - by determining its index of the priority-array
- finally select the last item into the result array

Code:

```
string sample="|NR|ABC,777,666,hhh|NR|DEF,444,,|NR|GHI,888,222,";
string[] priority = { "DEF", "GHI", "ABC", "JKL", "MNO" };
string[] result = sample.Split(new[] { "|NR|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(x => x.Split(new[] {','},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                        .OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(priority,x.First()))
                        .Select(x => x.Last())
                        .ToArray(); //444,222,hhh
```